# I have port 8080 but if i don't use in link adres :8080 isn't working

Tags: xampp, port

I have port 8080 but if i don't use in link adres :8080 site looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtAXi.png) What am I doing wrong?

hots:

`127.0.0.1  danzuz.eu`

`127.0.0.2  wordpress1.danzuz.eu`

`127.0.0.3  wordpress2.danzuz.eu`

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```html
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@danzuz.eu
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
ServerName danzuz.eu
ServerAlias danzuz.eu
ErrorLog "logs/danzuz.eu-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/danzuz.eu-access.log" common
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@wordpress1.danzuz.eu
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/danzuzeu"
ServerName wordpress1.danzuz.eu
ServerAlias wordpress1.danzuz.eu
ErrorLog "logs/wordpress1.danzuz-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/wordpress1.danzuz-access.log" common
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/danzuzeu">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@wordpress2.danzuz.eu
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/wordpress"
ServerName wordpress2.danzuz.eu
ServerAlias wordpress2.danzuz.eu
ErrorLog "logs/wordpress2.danzuz-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/wordpress2.danzuz-access.log" common
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/wordpress">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for help :( and sorry if i make wrong with my post it is my first time and sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question that will elicit responses. This question isn't clear as to what your problem is

Comment: I want to delete a port with a page address because when I want to enter a specific page directory, it always directs me to the main directory if there is no port.
when i use wordpress1.danzuz.eu i want go to C:/xampp/htdocs/www/danzuzeu